# Sharepoint Phone SDK installation for Visual Studio 2013 Professional

Tags: windows-phone-8, sdk, visual-studio-2013, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to install the SP2013 Phone SDK on my desktop computer (Win 8.1, 64bit) running Visual Studio 2013. VS2013 comes prepackaged with the Windows Phone 8 SDK, but the SP2013 Phone SDK installer fails to recognize it and promptly cancels the installation.
Is the Sharepoint Phone SDK not supposed to run on VS2013?

Comment: More than 1 year later, having the same issue. Any of you guys found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

The requirements for the SP2013 Phone templates (SDK) are `VS2012` and `Phone SDK version 8.0`.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163943.aspx

Comment: @MartinEvans: No, you didn't improve formatting at all.  Backticks are for code only.